# Modifying HTTPS response packet on the fly with mitmproxy

Tags: python, linux, packet-capture, mitmproxy, tampering

I am trying to implement an mitmproxy addon script, in order to tamper with a particular https packet data - which is by the way decrypted on the fly through mitmproxy's certificate injection.

I am following this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914515/5500552) to a rather similar question, as well as [this tutorial](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-overview/) from the mitmproxy docs, but without any success so far.

The packet I'm targeting comes from `https://api.example.com/api/v1/user/info`.
Now here is the whole python script I wrote so as to tamper with this packet data,  based upon the aforementioned sources :

```
from mitmproxy import ctx

class RespModif:
    def _init_(self):
        self.num = 0

    def response(self, flow):
        ctx.log.info("RespModif triggered")

        if flow.request.url == "https://api.example.com/api/v1/user/info":
            ctx.log.info("RespModif triggered -- In the if statement")   
            self.num = self.num + 1
            ctx.log.info("RespModif -- Proceeded to %d response modifications "
                         "of the targetted URLs" % self.num)

addons = [
    RespModif()
]
```

Checking out the events log, I'm able to see that the first log information ("*RespModif triggered*") is being reported onto the log, but the two other log infos (done from inside the `if` statement) are never reported, which means I think that the `if` statement ***does never succeed***.

Is there something wrong with my code ?
How can I get the `if` statement to succeed ?

***PS***: The target URL is definitely correct, plus I'm using it with a registered account from the client application that is being sniffed with mitmproxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `pretty_url` attribute ?
Something like :

```
if flow.request.pretty_url == "https://api.example.com/api/v1/user/info":
    ....
```

`pretty_url` attribute handles full *domain name* whereas `url` only deals with corresponding *ip address*.
Also logging the content of `pretty_url` should allow to see what exact URL is going through and give more visibility as to what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Yes I just tried it out, unfortunately does not work either ... I've tried with other valid URLs as well and the `if` statement never succeed with them either ! How is that possible ??

Comment: you can debug it by printing flow.request.url or flow.request. pretty_url to see exactly URL.

Comment: Your advice, Sir, made me finally pull this off !! Thanx a lot, but please add your comment to the answer, and explain also how pretty_url handles domain name as opposed to url which deals only with ip address, so I can accept the answer !

Comment: I don't know it deeply :) I just searched a bit and made a small advice...